# Could not connect to the docker container

Tags: docker, networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian, federated-learning

I have a federated server (flower framework) running in a docker container in the raspberry pi device in the same network as the client (My laptop). The client is not able to establish a connection with the server.

`Raspberry pi host ip address: 192.168.0.104 Docker container ip address: 170.17.0.2`

I enabled port forwarding for the docker container from 8080 to 8000. When I try to connect the client to the server’s 192.168.0.104:8000 address and port. I get the error

`status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE                                                                                                                                 details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNAVAILABLE: ipv4:192.168.0.104:8000: WSA Error"                                                     debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNAVAILABLE: ipv4:192.168.0.104:8000: WSA Error {created_time:"2023-08-19T13:55:0 7.018340428+00:00", grpc_status:14}"`

I have disabled the firewall in the client (my laptop).

I searched whether raspberry pi has any firewall blocking the connection, but I haven’t found any solid information. Am I missing anything, sharing any information or direction in which I must head will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [Solved] Need to pass network parameter in docker run
```--network="host"```
The container will share the network stack with the docker host. Followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=2

Comment: `--network=host` generally disables Docker's networking layer, and it's almost never necessary.  Right now you've only loosely described the application setup, but without a lot of details; can you further [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?